Pronouncing “安い” “薄い” and “不味い” as “やしい” “うしい” and “まじい” respectively
Contracting the final two vowels of an i-adjective to impart a rougher tone seems to be fairly popular at least in fiction in character role type language as in “ない” to “ねえ” or “うるさい” to “うるせえ”. “悪い” to “わりい” also seems fairly common and I've seen “暑い” to “あちい” exactly once. Leading me to believe that in theory the three examples should be able to be contractable as such but I've never seen it so does this feel more uncommon and is the /ui/ -> /ii/ contraction simply not as common as the /ai/ -> /ee/ contraction or does it sound as natural and common to use them?

Both are common contractions. See Use of 悪ィ over 悪い.

I agree that the /ui/-to-/ii/ contraction is not as common as the /ai/-to-/ee/ contraction. Here's my personal impression (* = slang):

わりい (悪い), あちい (暑い), ねみい (眠い), だりい (怠い), さみい (寒い), きちい (きつい): Very common
まじい (不味い), かりい (軽い): Common
にびい (鈍い), ふりい (古い), あかりい (明るい), がめちい (がめつい): Uncommon but used
やしい (安い), にきい (憎い), かいい (痒い), はじい (ハズい*), なちい (なつい*): Might have heard it, but very rare
うしい (薄い), あやいい (危うい): Never heard it

Note that this list is about whether I've seen these in manga or social media, not about whether you should use them. You seem to understand this, but even items marked as "very common" can sound fairly rude and unsocial if used inappropriately.
